# While Publsiing the private app get the following error

Tags: android, google-play-console

com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request

```
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "message" : "Invalid value at 'track_config.releases[0].status' (TYPE_ENUM), \"Completed\"",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid value at 'track_config.releases[0].status' (TYPE_ENUM), \"Completed\"",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```